# Issue with leadbolt and admob mediation

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate a custom banner for leadbolt with admob mediation.  I followed the directions on the [Banners Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/ads/mobile-ads-sdk/mediation/custom-events/banners) and created a CustomAd class, and for parameter I set it to the section ID # from the banner leadbolt dashboard.  I changed the ad unit id in the xml from my publisher ID to the mediation ID.  I set the mediation to 100% in the AdMobCustomEvent, but i'm getting the error:

```
Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?
```

Basically do I need to change any of the code in the CustomAd class or add any extra code to my other classes to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you Integrate the sdk from leadbolt ? If not download the sdk/.jar file and integrate it like you did with admob. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/ad-network-mediation